# Parsing a string using bash function

Tags: bash, array

I'm trying to replace some codes with bash function to reuse it. So my previous codes are:

```
#!/bin/bash
set aline=" dsfsdf | fsdfff | yuhfd "
set line_parsed=`echo $aline | tr '|' "\n"`
echo ${line_parsed[1]}
```

Which outputs `dsfsdf`.

Now, if I'm trying to put the sentence in a function, I cannot get it right:

```
#!/bin/bash
parseLine ()
{
set line_parsed=`$echo $1 | tr '|' "\n"`
echo ${line_parsed[1]}
}
set aline=" dsfsdf | fsdfff | yuhfd "
parseLine $aline
```

Is there a syntax error?

Comment: `$echo`?  ShellSheck is your friend. http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: #!/bin/bash
parseLine (){ line_parsed=$(echo "$1" | tr '|' "\n"); echo "${line_parsed[1]}";}
aline=" dsfsdf | fsdfff | yuhfd "
parseLine "$aline"

Comment: Its still not working, reporting "syntax error: unexpected end of file" even if it passed in spellcheck.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an array from string, use:

```
IFS='|' read -r -a line_parsed <<< "$aline"
```

---

- `IFS='|'` sets bashs [internal field seprator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) to `|`
- `read` reads from its standard input file descriptor

  - `-r` Backslash does not act as an escape character.
  - `-a line_parsed` create an array named `line_parsed`
- `<<< "$aline"` is a [Here string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html), which passes the contents of `$aline` to `read`s standard input.

You will now have an array. `echo "${line_parsed[0]}"` will give you the first element of the splitted string.

---

All of that in a function:

```
parseLine ()
{
  IFS='|' read -r -a line_parsed <<< "$1"
  echo "${line_parsed[0]}"
}
```

This can now be called like this:

```
$ parseLine "dsfsdf | fsdfff | yuhfd "
dsfsdf
```